# Can someone explain to me in simple terms rather or not i can boot my pc from a virtualbox created drive?

Tags: windows, mac-osx

hell everyone. i believe there is a post about this but advanced users tend to leave advanced answers when speaking amongst each other, so heres what im doing (keep in mind im not a total noob, i pick up things pretty easy which is how i got this far but how this works needs some clearing up for me)..

i got osx86 to run successfully via virtuabox. i know there any many was to install this however this was the only way that worked on this pc. now i know that virtual box creates a "drive" on my harddisk to run the image on. my questions are:

1) when i installed the OS does it actually install in to that "drive" and can run it without the iso present after install?

2) can i map the pc to actually boot from that "drive" and bypass my original OS all together? and how? (as simple as possible)

3) and last is it possible to copy the entire "drive" to a usb drive and boot/run on a different pc? how?

i want to thank anyone in advance who is willing to take the time out there day to assist me with this..it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 2) may be possible some day in the future.  'They' are working on [bare metal hypervisors for the desktop](http://www.networkworld.com/news/2009/012109-citrix-plans-bare-metal-desktop.html).  It just isn't ready yet.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, it installs to a file on the main computer. This file is presented as if it was a disk drive to the virtual computer. It's installed there, so you shouldn't need the ISO anymore.
2. No you can't directly boot from the virtual drive, because it's not a real hard drive, it's a file on a real hard drive.
3. Yes, but how exactly will have to be answered by someone who knows more about VirtualBox than I do.

Comment: For virtual box just copy the vdi file to the new location and setup a new VM and use that file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sun/Oracle VirtualBox creates a .vdi file which is a virtual disk image. There is lots of information about vdi files [here](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=8046)
2. This is not currently possible. I wouldn't be surprised if it became possible in the future.
3. Just copy the vdi file to a usb drive. It's probably a good idea to change the UUID of the copied vdi too.

   `vboxmanage internalcommands setvdiuuid <filename>.vdi`

You will need to install VirtualBox on the target computer as you can't run it from the pen drive. Once you've done that add a new machine to VirtualBox selecting the option to `Use existing hard disk` at the appropriate prompt and navigate to the usb drive . The rest is as normal.

**Edit:** It's possible to create a portable virtual box installation using the instructions found [**here**](http://maketecheasier.com/install-virtualbox-in-usb/2010/01/02). I tried it with VBox 3.2.4 and an XP SP3 vm and it works.

Comment: thank you for your answer....perhaps you can help me with this, the other pc does not have a dvd drive. i want to install osx86 directly and have downloaded and used vmware as well as some other software to mount the iso but it will not run the installation. instead when i mount the iso it just opens a folder with the iso contents. im assuming it wont run cause windows being already open doesnt reconized the files. how can i get it to run?

Comment: You can mount an iso directly to a virtual machine as it it where a cd/dvd. In VB select the machine then select settings ->storage. Click Add attachment button and select Add CD/DVD device. Select the new device then on the right in the Attributes panel click on the Open Virtual Media Manager button. Click Add then navigate to the .iso you want to use. Click OK then Click the .iso in the panel and click select. It should now be attached to you machine.

Answer (score 0):

you can try creating a raw vmdk. i don't know how from the top of my head, but it's googleable